# Alphabetical Ranges?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure if this is the the correct thing that I'm looking for, can someone point me in the right direction?

We've got a few different types of data running through this particular elasticsearch instance because it's all part of the same API. What I need for this particular set of data is to be able to search and return all results that start with groups of letters like A-G, H-N, O-U, V-Z.

I'm not sure if this is considered a range or aggregation or just something I have to do programmatically after the search. Can someone point me in the correct direction? I'm honestly not even sure what terms to google for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three aspects to something like that.

You can leverage the `multi-fields` functionality for whatever field you want the groups to be based on (let's say a `name` field).  There will be a `name.first_letter` path for this purpose that is analyzed with the [`edge_ngram` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) with `min_gram` = 1 and `max_gram` = 1.  So, this path just allows searching and filtering by the first letter of the name.

In order to get the four buckets, the [`filters` bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) can be used with the `terms` filter applied against the `name.first_letter` where you filter values representing the buckets `['A', 'B', ..., 'G']`.

However, the bucket aggregations just return doc counts.  You will need to specify a sub-aggregation leveraging the [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to actually pull the bucketed hits.